# youtube-dl downloaded part of a video, gave an error, now says it has already downloaded the video

Tags: video, download, youtube

So I started a download from youtube with youtube-dl, it got about 600mb and quit with this error:

```
[http @ 003f7c80] HTTP error 403 Forbidden time=00:42:19.46 bitrate=2127.1kbits/s http://www.youtube.com/api/manifest/hls_playlist/id/z6kgvhG3AkI.1/itag/96/source/yt_live_broadcast/ratebypass/ yes/live/1/cmbypass/yes/newshard/yes/hls_chunk_host/www.youtube.com/gir/yes/dg_shard/z6kgvhG3AkI.1_96/playlist _type/CLEAN/maudio/1/pmbypass/yes/cp/U0hYRlVUT19GUUNOOF9NTlNKOkZDN053d25faEZM/upn/uVxu3wbYMiM/sver/3/fexp/9338 02,939100,938612,919007,944500,916608,936910,936913/ip/67.202.189.27/ipbits/8/expire/1391591917/sparams/ip,ipb its,expire,id,itag,source,ratebypass,live,cmbypass,newshard,hls_chunk_host,gir,dg_shard,playlist_type,maudio,p mbypass,cp/signature/5B4B59529EA0B5F047D982A927E89BA5E4675F10.0B66625393DE35607614790C5B3DA49EA02B43F5/key/dg_ yt0/file/index.m3u8: Input/output error
```

I tried using the -c to continue but it just says I already downloaded the file. The video should be over 1.3gb or so thought so I know something is up.

Any ideas? Can youtube-dl start a new download midway thru the video that I could later edit together with the first part?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the file and started over?

Comment: I was trying to avoid that since it is halfway downloaded. I found out that youtube-dl will not start downloading a video except from the beginning. Perhaps another command line tool can?

Comment: @Kruug Thanks for your fast reply though. :)

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I figured out a solution. When youtube-dl errored out it named the final file with the video title and an .mp4 extension. ex: filename.mp4

When it usually stops midstream it saves in the same way but with a .part extension. ex: filename.mp4.part

I renamed the file, adding .part to the end, ran youtube-dl -c filename.mp4.part and off it went continuing on as if nothing had happened and without having to restart from the beginning. :)

Comment: Hopefully they've fixed this problem since then :)